# Is there a Google Sheet function that will parse out Country Name and Number into two different columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In cell A1, I have data that looks like this:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Finland 100 France 2000 Germany 1840 Great Britain 1333 Greece 64 |

I want the output to look like this:

|  | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finland | 100 |
| 2 | France | 2000 |
| 3 | Germany | 1840 |
| 4 | Great Britain | 1333 |
| 5 | Greece | 64 |
|  |  |  |

There are other countries + values, but I wanted to illustrate that sometimes there are countries with multiple words, which is causing me to struggle with the problem.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", FILTER(SPLIT(A1, " "), ISNUMBER(SPLIT(A1, " ")))), " "))
```

gets all of the numbers, but fails to get the country names on a single row.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=index(split(regexreplace(tocol(split(regexreplace(A1,"(\d)( )(\D)","$1|$3"),"|")),"( )(\d)","|$2"),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: You just saved me so much time, that solution works perfectly, thank you!